# ultimo elemento array

Tags: javascript, array

que tal gente hago una consulta, me piden emular la funcion pop que duvuelve el ultimo elemento de un array, tenia entendido que array.length -1 devolvia la ultima posicion pero al ponerlo en el codigo me devuelve el penultimo elemento este es mi codigo:

```
function pop(arr){
return arr.length - 0
} 

function pop(arr){
return arr.length - 1
}
```

let result = pop([1,2,3,4,5] // result 5

let result = pop([1,2,3,4,5] // result 4

a que se debe?

Comment: Te aconsejo usar otros elementos en tu array así puedes identificar mejor el problema. Desde poner los números en orden decreciente hasta cambiarlos por texto. Cómo pudiste darte cuenta en la respuesta, tu función devuelve una posición, no un elemento.

Answer (score 5):

tu codigo esta totalmente mal, y por eso pensas que devuelve algo, pero estas devolviendo cualquier cosa...

> tenia entendido que array.length -1 devolvia la ultima posicion

Y estas totalmente en lo correcto

pero....

```js
function pop(arr){
     return arr.length - 0
} 

console.log(pop([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

lo que esta haciendo, es preguntar cuanto mide el array `arr.length` y restarle cero!!!

para devolver un elemento del array, tenes que usar el array, y decirle que indice devolver (de ahi que uses arr.length-1, porque el primer elemento del array, es el 0)

```js
function pop(arr){
     return arr[arr.length - 1];
} 

console.log(pop([10,20,30,40,50]));
```

Para acceder al elemento de un array, se usa el nombre que le diste al array, y se aclara que indice, entre los corchetes: `nombre_array[posicion]`

Comment: si me queda claro que al pedirle la length -0 coincide con 5 y al pedirle length -1 coincide con 4, gracias por la ayuda me ayudo a entenderlo mejor.

Comment: de nada, pero @GualbertDev sabes como funciona el sitio? si alguna respuesta te sirvio, y soluciona tu problema, aceptas la respuesta... lee el [tour]

Comment: @GualbertDev si esta respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, marcala como aceptada, revisa [tour].